# how to create a proper bool Employee::operator==(const Employee & rhs) const

Tags: c++

I'm fairly new to C++ programming. I currently have an 
error C2678: binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const Employee'

This error is point to line

```
if (*iLoc == aID)
```

I believe I am suppose to create a

```
bool Employee::operator==(const Employee & rhs) const
{
}
```

that will override the error. I think I need to make a overloaded `==` operator that is able to compare and `unsigned int` to an `Employee` object. But I am stuck. I was wondering if anyone is able to help. Part of my main.cpp is included.

```
bool Employee::operator==(const Employee & rhs) const
    {
}

void searchItem(const List<Employee>& l1)
{
if (l1.size() == 0)
    cout << "List empty!\n";

else
{

    unsigned int ID;
    cout << "Enter ID#: ";
    cin >> ID;

    size_t index = 0;
    List<Employee>::const_iterator iLoc = l1.begin();
    while (iLoc != l1.end())
    {
        if (*iLoc == aID)
        {
            cout << "Employee's Name:  " << aID << " found at node # " << index << endl;
            break;
        }
        index++;
        iLoc++;
    }
    if (iLoc == l1.end())
        cout << "ID# " << aID << " not found!\n";
}
}

void removeItem(List<Employee>& l1)
{
    if (l1.size() == 0)
        cout << "List empty!\n";
    else
    {
        unsigned int aID;
    cout << "Enter ID#: ";
    cin >> aID;

    size_t index = 0;
    List<Employee>::iterator iLoc = l1.begin();
    while (iLoc != l1.end())
    {
        if (*iLoc == aID)
        {
            cout << "Value " << aID << " removed from node # " << index << endl;
            l1.erase(iLoc);
            break;
        }
        index++;
        iLoc++;
    }
    if (iLoc == l1.end())
        cout << "Value not found!\n";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the function `void removeItem(List<Employee>&)`, in the line

```
if (*iLoc == aID)
```

you are comparing a dereferenced iterator, i.e. an `Employee`, to an `unsigned int` (`aID`). The right hand side must be an `Employee` also, or `Employee` must have an implicit constructor that takes an `unsigned int` as a parameter, so the compiler may be able to convert `aID` to `Employee(aID)` when trying to resolve the call to `(*iLoc).operator==(aID)`.

Solution: define either

```
bool Employee::operator==(const Employee & rhs) const
{
    return comparison_here;
}
```

and make sure `Employee` has a constructor that takes an `unsigned int`, or create an overloaded `operator==` that takes an `unsigned int`,

```
bool Employee::operator==(unsigned int rhs) const
{
    return comparison_here;
}
```

You may also consider defining `operator==` as a non-member function, so it can also take `unsigned int` as a left-hand-side parameter. More details: [Operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)

Comment: Do you mean something like this? 
bool Employee::operator==(const Employee & rhs) const
{
 return (ID == rhs.ID);
}

Comment: @OrangePineapple you should write something like `return rhs.aID == aID`. Try finding some good books/tutorials.

Comment: I tried looking online and looked at some textbooks. Still haven't anywhere.